# Making a matrix out of a list with certain repeating rows and columns in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have a list of data which look likes this in R:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsqFB.png)

In the entire list, the "Tenor" column is repeating the same 11 elements and the "last update" column changes every 11 element once.
I want to make a matrix with the Tenors as the column names and last update dates as the row names. The matrix should be field with the corresponding bid yields.
I do not know how to create such a matrix which would put the corresponding bid yields in the matrix.

The dput(my data) is like this
"2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", "10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", "30Y", 
"1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", "10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", 
"30Y", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", "10Y", "15Y", "20Y", 
"25Y", "30Y", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", "10Y", "15Y", 
"20Y", "25Y", "30Y", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", "10Y", 
"15Y", "20Y", "25Y", "30Y", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", 
"10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", "30Y")), .Names = c("Bid Yield", 
"Last Update", "Tenor"), row.names = c(NA, -25256L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `xtabs`

```
xtabs(BidYield ~ LastUpdate + Tenor, df1)
#         Tenor
#LastUpdate     10Y   15Y    1Y   20Y   25Y    2Y   30Y    3Y    4Y    5Y    7Y
#  2011-04-15 4.807 5.233 0.666 5.411 5.504 1.315 5.504 2.105 2.780 3.355 4.180
#  2011-04-18 4.785 5.206 0.653 5.395 5.491 1.280 5.486 2.053 2.727 3.311 4.142
```

If the column names have spaces, etc, use backquotes around the column name

```
names(df1)[1:2] <- c("Bid Yield", "Last Update")
xtabs(`Bid Yield` ~ `Last Update` + Tenor, df1)
#   Tenor
#Last Update    10Y   15Y    1Y   20Y   25Y    2Y   30Y    3Y    4Y    5Y    7Y
#  2011-04-15 4.807 5.233 0.666 5.411 5.504 1.315 5.504 2.105 2.780 3.355 4.180
# 2011-04-18 4.785 5.206 0.653 5.395 5.491 1.280 5.486 2.053 2.727 3.311 4.142
```

If we need the 'Tenor' columns to be ordered, an option is to convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified based on the value

```
library(gtools)
df1$Tenor <- factor(df1$Tenor, levels = mixedsort(unique(df1$Tenor)))
xtabs(`Bid Yield` ~ `Last Update` + Tenor, df1)
#            Tenor
#Last Update     1Y    2Y    3Y    4Y    5Y    7Y   10Y   15Y   20Y   25Y   30Y
#  2011-04-15 0.666 1.315 2.105 2.780 3.355 4.180 4.807 5.233 5.411 5.504 5.504
#  2011-04-18 0.653 1.280 2.053 2.727 3.311 4.142 4.785 5.206 5.395 5.491 5.486
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(BidYield = c(0.666, 1.315, 2.105, 2.78, 3.355, 
4.18, 4.807, 5.233, 5.411, 5.504, 5.504, 0.653, 1.28, 2.053, 
2.727, 3.311, 4.142, 4.785, 5.206, 5.395, 5.491, 5.486), 
  LastUpdate = c("2011-04-15", 
"2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", 
"2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", "2011-04-15", 
"2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", 
"2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", "2011-04-18", 
"2011-04-18"), Tenor = c("1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", "7Y", 
"10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", "30Y", "1Y", "2Y", "3Y", "4Y", "5Y", 
"7Y", "10Y", "15Y", "20Y", "25Y", "30Y")), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22"))
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work since I have space in the column names. I tried to use colnames <- c(BidYield, LastUpdate, Tenor)
colnames(bidyield.JPM) <- colnames
lapply(bidyield.JPM, setNames, colnames) but it still doesn't change the column names.

Comment: @Agi In that case just add backquotes for the spaced column names

Comment: It gives me an error as follows: 
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  invalid term in model formula

Comment: @Agi Can you please use `dput(yourdata)` and update your post with the output of that so that I get the correct structure of your data for testing

Comment: @Agi I tried by changing the column names to spaces, (updated) and it is working fine for me

Comment: I got it. I was putting ' instead of `. Sorry for that! Thanks

Comment: One more question on how I can put the columns in ascending order so it would start from 1Y up to 30Y?

Comment: Thank you! How can I select columns and rows in this format?

Comment: I mean if I want to select the 1Y tenor column, how can I do so?

Comment: @Agi Just do  `xtabs(`Bid Yield` ~ `Last Update` + Tenor, df1)[, '1Y', drop = FALSE]`